# why doesn't this drop-down menu work with mouseover and leave?

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, mouseover, mouseleave

I want it to display "you" under "Home" when hovering and disappearing        when mouse leaving:

```
// HTML
<ul>
<li><a id="homeBox" href="#">Home</a>
<ul><li><a id="homeSub" href="#">you</a></li></ul>
</li>
</ul>

// javaScript
var homeB= document.getElementById("homeBox");
var homeS = document.getElementById("homeSub")
homeBox.mouseover = function() {
    var homeS = document.getElementById("homeSub").style.display= "block";
}
homeBox.mouseleave = function() {
    var homeS = document.getElementById("homeSub").style.display= "none";
}
// CSS
<style>
    ul li ul li a #homeSub {display: hidden;}
</style>
```

Comment: the "homeBox" is the id and the variable for it is homeB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were quite a few issues. If you have any questions let me know

```
homeBox.mouseover
```

There is no `homeBox` use `homeB`, and `mouseover` isnt an event handler `onmouseover` is.

```
homeB.onmouseover
```

---

```
ul li ul li a #homeSub {display: hidden;}
```

This is looking for a link with a child that has the id `homeSub`, and `display: hidden` should be `display: none`

```
ul li ul li a#homeSub {display: none;}
```

---

```
var homeS = document.getElementById("homeSub").style.display= "block";
```

You've already defined homeS

```
homeS.style.display = 'block';
```

---

```js
var homeB = document.getElementById("homeBox");
var homeS = document.getElementById("homeSub");
homeB.onmouseover = function() {
    homeS.style.display = "block";
}
homeB.onmouseout = function() {
    homeS.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
ul li ul li a#homeSub {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><a id="homeBox" href="#">Home</a>
<ul><li><a id="homeSub" href="#">you</a></li></ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: wow..this is very helpful..thanks for editing it nicely..sure !

Answer (score 1):

Why Javascript? Use simple CSS Solution.

```
  ul li ul{display: none;}
  ul li:hover ul{display: block;}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/k3kaoxed/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
<li><a id="homeBox" href="#">Home</a>
<ul><li><a id="homeSub" href="#">you</a></li></ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

-Use `onmouseover` instead of `mouseover`

-Put your Javascript between script-tags, and in a function that will execute after the page has loaded (and use 'none' instead of 'hidden').

```
<script>
(function() {
    var homeB= document.getElementById("homeBox");

    var homeS = document.getElementById("homeSub");

    homeB.onmouseover = function() {
        homeS.style.display = "block";
    }
    homeB.onmouseleave = function() {
        homeS.style.display= "none";
    }
})();
</script>
```

-And adjust your stylesheet:

```
<style>
    #homeSub {display: none;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any javascript for this functionality. Just use CSS - http://jsfiddle.net/akq1e5o6/

P.S.: there is no avaliable `hidden` value for `display` property